# How to add file dynamically in META-INF folder using gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am migrating a maven project to a gradle one. In maven project, we used to have profiles for different environments and it adds context.xml from a dir to META-INF of the generated war.

The resource dir structure is as follows:

```
|   |-- resources
|   |   |-- META-INF-Contexts
|   |   |   |-- dev
|   |   |   |   `-- context.xml
|   |   |   |-- qa
|   |   |   |   `-- context.xml
|   |   |   |-- prod
|   |   |       `-- context.xml
|   |   |-- app.properties
|   `-- webapp
|       |-- favicon.ico
|       `-- WEB-INF
|           `-- web.xml
```

Now in gradle I want to pass a property (env) and depending on the value, it should take the proper context.xml file and place it under META-INF directory.

The approach I tried is as follows:

```
ext {
    isDev = System.properties['env'] == 'dev'
    isQa = System.properties['env'] == 'qa'
    isProd = System.properties['env'] == 'prod'
}

war {
    if (isDev) {
        metaInf { from 'src/main/resources/META-INF-Contexts/dev/context.xml' }
    } else if (qa) {
        metaInf { from 'src/main/resources/META-INF-Contexts/qa/context.xml' }
    } else {
        metaInf { from 'src/main/resources/META-INF-Contexts/prod/context.xml' }
    }
}
```

but it is not putting the context.xml inside the META-INF directory. Any help would be appreciated.